# Logging out of pages on screen lock?

Tags: windows, firefox, firefox-extensions

I want to log out of web sites such as GMail, Twitter, etc when I lock my PC. How can I achieve that?

I'm using Firefox on Windows 7.

I've searched the Firefox extensions and haven't found anything.

Comment: @Ƭᴇcʜιᴇ007 how about if I rephrase as "I want to log out of web sites such as GMail, Twitter, etc when I lock my PC. How can I achieve that? I'm using Firefox on Windows 7." Would that be acceptable to you?

Comment: Yup, please ensure you also share any research you've done (what you've tried already, why it didn't work, etc.).

Comment: Actively logging out of websites would be a pain due to the need to script it out.  Would simply closing the browser on lock suffice (it'd be much easier)?

Comment: Not an option. I have tons of tabs open (500+) and opening the browser is always a drag.